# python returning a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to be able to take 2 values from a file in a function. then return both in a dictionary. this is what I have so far

```
def getWeatherData():
    f = open("/Users/kamal/Desktop/text.html",'r')
    myfile = f.read()
    w = myfile.find('''<tr><th colspan="15" class="wxo-th-bkg table-date">''')

    temperature = myfile[w+494:w+496]
    temp = temperature.strip()
    cloudyness = myfile[w+396:w+415]
    cloud = cloudyness.strip()
    cloud = cloud.replace("</p></div","")
    print(temp,cloud)
    dictionnary = {"temp":str(temp),"Condition":str(cloud)}
    f.close()
    return dictionnary

getWeatherData()
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Can you describe what issue you are currently facing? Is something not working as expected? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The code looks reasonable, but very brittle. Consider using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to actually parse the HTML and extract element values robustly.

Comment: @9000 the program I am writing doesnt allow any external help,

Comment: @Ouroborus When I try to use the dictionnary outside the function, it just gives me errors saying the dictionnary is not defined, even when I try to print it

Comment: @AndrewZick When I try to use the dictionnary outside the function, it just gives me errors saying the dictionnary is not defined, even when I try to print it

Comment: Try `dictionnary = getWeatherData()`...

Comment: @Kamal when you return the dictionary from the function, are you assigning what the function returns to a variable? E.g. dictionnary = getWeatherData()? Then you can print d and/or use d and it should have your values. Just returning a variable doesn't make it available everywhere.

Comment: @EdWard It works! Thanks a lot man! Didn't know I had to do that

Comment: @Kamal glad that EdWard helped fix it! Here's a short article talking about the problem you had, which is variable scope, just in case you want to read a little more about python. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Kamal _the program I am writing doesnt allow any external help_ The standard library includes an [HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to call a function multiple times to find different values from a file, you need to introduce a parameter to your function that you can use to find location in your file. For example:

```
def getWeatherData(location):
   # your code
```

if you want to assign your dictionary to a variable, you need to use

```
table = getWeatherData()
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code, it just runs through a files and gets 2 specific pieces which do not change locations and remain static, I just need help returning the dictionnary I made in the code

Answer (score 2):

```
dictionnary = getWeatherData()
```

and you can print or access `dictionnary` after this.